# RecyclerView not returning correct number of lines in TextView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

In my RecyclerView adapter, I'm using `getLineCount()` on a TextView to return the number of lines a TextView has, but it returns 0 (zero) every time.

If I scroll down the RecyclerView, and then scroll back up, it will return the correct number of lines.

Why is it doing this and how can I make it so that it returns the correct number of lines initially?

Here is my `onBindViewHolder()` method in my RecyclerView adapter:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Post post = posts.get(position);

    holder.postText.setText(post.getText());

    holder.postText.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            int numLines = holder.postText.getLineCount();

            Log.d("# of lines", String.valueOf(numLines));
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is put an ViewTreeObserver on the textview and listen for the global layout event.  You should have your line number count there

Comment: I've never seen any performance hit.  Don't forget: This is a recyclerview.  So it only loads like 5 or 7 items at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you want to achieve, yet you seem to do this wrong. Especially I do not like this `Runnable`. As for `getLineCount()` - it will give you the correct number of lines only after a layout pass. That means the TextView must have been drawn at least once.

Comment: If I remove `Runnable`, it also doesn't return the correct number of lines initially (it will return 0). If I scroll down a bit and then scroll back up, it will return the correct number of lines.